Find the oblique asymptote of $f(x)=\frac{x^2\arctan(x)}{4x-1}$ as $x \to -\infty$.
The problem:
Find the oblique asymptote of $f(x)=\frac{x^2\arctan(x)}{4x-1}$ as $x \to -\infty$.
The solution:
No solution is provided for this problem, except that the oblique asymptote of $f(x)=\frac{x^2\arctan(x)}{4x-1}$ as $x \to \infty$ is $y=\frac{1}{32}(4\pi x+\pi-8)$ and the vertical asymptote is $x=\frac{1}{4}$.
What I have tried:
$$\lim_{x \to -\infty}f(x)=\lim_{x \to -\infty}\frac{x^2\arctan(x)}{4x-1}=\lim_{x \to -\infty}\frac{x^2}{4x-1}\cdot\arctan(x)=\lim_{x \to -\infty}\frac{x}{4-\frac{1}{x}}\cdot\arctan(x)=\frac{\lim_{x \to -\infty}(x)}{4-0}\cdot(-\frac{\pi}{2})$$
My question:
I really have no clue how to go about solving this problem. Please, help.

@Sien Can update your question with your definition of an oblique asymptote? It will also help you to work on the problem. By the way, how can you even start without such a definition?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptote#General_computation_of_oblique_asymptotes_for_functions

$m=\lim_{x \to -\infty}\frac{x^2\arctan(x)}{x(4x-1)}=-\frac{\pi}{8}$ and $n=\lim_{x \to -\infty}(\frac{x^2\arctan(x)}{4x-1}+\frac{\pi}{8}x)$? And then $y=mx+n$? Is that it?

Using the formula to compute the oblique asymptote you have:
$$m=\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{x^2\tan^{-1}(x)}{x(4x-1)}=-\frac{\pi}8 $$
and
$$n=\lim_{x\to -\infty}\left(\frac{x^2\tan^{-1}(x)}{4x-1}+\frac{\pi}8 x\right)=\lim_{x\to -\infty} \frac{8 x^2\tan^{-1}(x)+\pi x(4x-1)}{8(4x-1)}=-\frac 14 -\frac{\pi}{32} $$
